# What are the tenets of Relevance Theory?

Tags: reference-request, pragmatics, discourse-analysis

What are the elements upon which one can base to process a speech with **relevance theory**?
I've been reading but I couldn't find an answer to this question.
I take the example of the **Speech act Theory** which is constituted of the *commissive*, *expressive*, *directive*, *assertive* and *declarative* acts. When analysing a text, one determines those five elements to conduct analysis.

Now in the case of **relevance theory**, upon which tenets one should focus and determine to conduct analysis.

Comment: Start by becoming familiar with Grice's Maxims, and note which ones can be violated by the speaker. It turns out that the Relevance Maxim is not under the control of the speaker, but rather the addressee, who expects relevance and will produce some if the speaker doesn't. That is, relevance controls all of pragmatics.

Comment: @jlawler Can implicature Theory be used to analyse a speech or is it exclusively used in cases of dialogue (like interviews for example)?

Comment: A speech is just a long dialogue with a disorganized response. But the speaker had better be aware of their audience.  I wouldn't claim anything for any "theory", but certainly a Gricean approach works for any kind of communicative language use.